# Where is Steven the Stegosaurus?

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, treasure-hunt

<sup><sup>This is an entry to the [Fortnightly Topic Challenge #27](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/5828/fortnightly-topic-challenge-27-treasure-hunt): [treasure-hunt](/questions/tagged/treasure-hunt).</sup></sup>

---

Steven the Stegosaurus has been kidnapped! It's now up to you to save him. When you enter Steven's cave, the only thing you can find is a note that Steven has left for you, along with a picture of him. Here it is: 
[image: Steven lives in Ireland]

> If you found this note, it means that I was unable to find my way home although I had many tools at my disposal. I was so intent on finding bacon that I ignored every other thing in my path, and I must have met some unfortunate demise. I have included a picture of me to remember me by. -Steven

Compiling the hints I made in the comments:

Hint #1:

> All the clues will be used.

Hint #2:

> There is more than one way to represent location on a map.

Hint #3:

> All the numbers in the solution in the imgur puzzle will be used in the final solution.

Hint #4:

> Steven's kidnappers did not take him very far.

Other hints:

> The way that Steven's location is represented only works in the country he is located in.

Comment: How big is Steven?  (Is he bigger than a breadbox?)

Comment: @Jasper Steven is a young stegosaurus, not much bigger than an average adult human.

Comment: Lot of I's make me feel there is binary in there. Also, bacon hints towards bacon cipher.

Comment: He's definitely a steganosaurus.

Comment: what's he going to do with bacon? Stegosaurus is/was herbivore.

Comment: The image text says "Steven lives in Ireland". Might be a clue.

Comment: Or just explaining the fact that he's green, haha

Comment: @Marius Might be his steganosaurus tendencies:p

Comment: I tried with 53.1424° N, 7.(255171)° W taking first number and adding it after the decimal sign in W coordinate. But not sure if this is right.

Comment: @Techidiot Have you seen hint #2?

Comment: Yup. Not sure what is the other way than using coordinates. Not sure how letter W helps

Comment: I think its [this](http://www.myloc8ion.com/maps/find_code8) but not sure how to use those numbers

Comment: then find a system where you can use the W

Comment: Oh its Irish grid reference system. I ill see what I can come up with. Not sure which number to w considered. I will start with first digits.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Steven is at

> ***Teaglac Muire, Main St, Meenane, Watergrasshill, Co. Cork, Ireland***

The image is

> Steganography! The note talks about many tools which leads to [this tool](http://manytools.org/hacker-tools/steganography-encode-text-into-image/). Decoding it with the website gives a huge string as
>
>      AHAETHATHERAHRBTHRAHBTRHARTAHAAEHATRBHBTHATRAEAHBTRHBTRAABBBAABHTRHRTAHRTHAHETHATEHETAHETHTBETHEBERHAETHAERTHAAIPBKBFGALBRTAKBEAALBRTALAHTRAHTRBHETHHTRAHBTRBTRBHBRTABYALAEAAKAAOBRTKKATRHIBPAKAAKBILAOLBUAAYHATGARAHBYBAOATYAIBREBRBCBVACXZABDFDGBJKNMAAUBRBBARTTABPATARBAJATJABJAJRTJABERHAAPIURBTBRJARAEYREBABITIBRTJBARJABWAAQBSBEBAUAIASAATRKABILPB
>
>  Cleaning the letters except A/B we get
>  *AAAABABAAAAABBAAABBAABBBA ABAAAABBAAAABBABABAABAAAB ABBBBABAAAAAABA BAAABABAAAAABBAAABBBBAABB AABBBAABAABAAABAABAA BBAABABBBAABAABBBAAAAAABB*
>
>
>  This is a Baconian cipher.
>  Decoding it gives
>  B IG GOI M G U R P IC R I G H T HE R E ZO J Y D
>
>  Which is ***BIG GO IMGUR PIC RIGHT HERE ZOJYD***
>
>  But..
>  Tried with zOjyd.png doesn't give any imgur. Still looking for it..
>
>  If I treat O as $0$ and j as i I get z0iyd(https://i.stack.imgur.com/z0iyd.png) which gives an image but it looks irrelevant and just a coincidence-
>  [image]
>
>
>  Now, either I am not getting the right way to interpret the imgur or may be there is an error. Will wait for the OP to confirm.

Going ahead

> OP confirms in the comment that the found image was irrelevant and we need to look for something related to albums. If @Carmeister's comment is right, we get -
>  https://i.stack.imgur.com/TaswV.jpg which is an imgur album with the following picture -
>
>  [image]
>
>  **Text form** 
>  **W**
>  A=2548828127
>  B=5097656254
>  AA=5097656254
>  BB=10195312508
>  AAA=?
>  BBB=15292968762
>
>  Upon checking, it looks like -
>  A = B/2
>  AA = BB/2
>  Hence, we get
>  AAA = BBB/2   i.e. AAA = 15292968762/2 = **7646484381**

Now as per hint, the numbers can be used only in Ireland

> So, I found Irish Grid Reference to be the next step for finding Steven. The grid looks like this - 
>
>
>  [image]
>
>  Now, we have letter **W** at the top. So, using [this tool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ap9MD.png) we can easily find Steven by entering the coordinate as **W 76464 84381**
>
>
>  [image: http://i.imgur.com/Ad80fcl.png]
>
>  Which is *Teaglac Muire, Main St, Meenane, Watergrasshill, Co. Cork, Ireland*

Comment: http://imgur.com/z0jyd ?

Comment: @CallumBradbury Nah. That can't be it :p

Comment: It's unlikely, for sure, but you never know...

Comment: Steven is not very fond of pythons, but he does loves picture albums.

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/zOjyd looks like what you want

Comment: @Techidiot I already replied.

Comment: @suomynonA Please confirm if the image obtained is right? Though, I don't see you left any clues for finding that. Also, not sure how to interpret *W*.

Comment: There is not another imgur image; you are on the last part of the puzzle. The clue you need is already mentioned on this thread somewhere.

Comment: So those numbers are some coordinates in Ireland I guess.

Comment: Perhaps it has something to do with coordinates? Just a guess.. though I just drowned Steven splitting the 10-digits number and use this as coordinates: 48.4381,-7.646

Comment: @MikeLimburg You have the right idea, but Steven does not like drowning :|

Comment: @Techidiot You also have the right idea, but Steven wasn't taken very far. Use the final clue=)

Comment: Steven's left fore limb doesn't look like a leg. I wonder whether  that shape is meaningful...

Comment: Remember there's more than one way to represent location on a map

Comment: @suomynonA This latest update is the best I could think of.

Comment: The above hint is already a big clue, the only thing I can tell you now is that all the numbers you get from the imgur puzzle will be used

Comment: Yes, this is correct=)